# phonegap + jquery mobile css not working in android app

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to get a simple jQuery in mobile, phonegap and android app.

The css isn't working on an android phone. I have gone through several posts here on the same topic, also tried storing the js and css assets locally, and adding the access in config.xml etc, but no success. 
Will appreciate any help.

Here is the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page Template</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css' />
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js'></script>







</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Header</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Hello jQuery Mobile!</p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is going to be to download the files and place them directly in your project. This will ensure the assets are loaded prior to your app displaying and prevent any runtime issues. Additionally, if the user opens your app and they don't have internet access everything will fail.

If it still isnt working locally, double check your pointers to the files and ensure you are placing them in the right path. Outside of that, there is no reason it shouldnt work.

Comment: I check that, with no success. Also, I tested in my browser and works good. But not in my Android...

Answer (score 1):

actually, if network is not available, your web page wouldn't be opened, and you are using jquery mobile CDN, it seems everything is ok! my suggestion is trying to modify your meta data  tag as following first for debug purpose:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width='device-width'/>
```

hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code on my android phone and it worked without any changes.
There is no need to add access in your config as this is just including a remote file and not making a cross browser request.

There is probably some problem with your phonegap app setup. I'm not sure but check that you are targeting the  correct sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dom's suggestion. If it still not working, turned on and look at your LogCat. I'm getting same problem with you, and LogCat says

`SyntaxError: parse error at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js:3195`.

I just comment line 3195 on that file, and the jQuery Mobile styles shows up

Answer (score -1):

give the head tags link in the following order

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquerymobile132min.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery191.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquerymobile132min.js"></script>
```